# What syntax does this for loop that reverses the key value follow in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

```py
dict_list={"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
inverse_dict=dict([val,key] for key,val in dict_list.items())
```

The for loop statements I have learned all start with `for`. I don't understand why there is a list before the keyword `for` in this statement, and I don't know how this statement can reverse the key-value pairs of the dictionary.

Comment: Note that if you want to read up on things, it's important to separate *statements* – things standing on their own on the start of a "line" – from *expressions* – things that make up other things. The weird ``for`` thing you are seeing is in the [expression specification](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries).

Comment: Yes, this isn't a for-loop statement at all! It is a generator expression, which works like list, dict, and set comprehensions. They are not statements, they are expressions, they evaluate to a value. Essentially these create iterables (generator, list, dict, or set) of various types and allow you to use arbitrarily nested mapping/filtering operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
inverse_dict = dict([val, key] for key, val in dict_list.items())
                    #---generator expression-------------------#
                    #--pair--#
```

works by virtue of [`dict()` accepting an iterable of pairs to turn into a dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#dict); the whole `(x for y in z)` production is a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) that yields an iterable.

In the expression, the `[val, key]` expression forms a key-value pair for each pair in `items`.
(It would be more idiomatic to use a tuple (`(val, key)`) instead of a list.)

The modern idiom for this is a dictionary comprehension, which is clearer to read:

```
dict_list = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
inverse_dict = {val: key for key, val in dict_list.items()}
```